# Mocha tests mocking function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, mocha.js, sinon

I'm testing backbone view, that have function:

```
attachSelect: function(id, route) {
    console.log(id);
    console.log(route);

    this.$(id).select2({
        ajax: {
            url: route,
            dataType: 'json',
            results: function(data) {
                var results = _.map(data, function(item) {
                    return {
                        id: item.id,
                        text: item.title
                    };
                });

                return {
                    results: results
                };
            },
            cache: true
        }
    });
}
```

I need to rewrite (mock) this fuction that, the looks like:

```
attachSelect: function(id, route) {
    console.log(id);
    console.log(route);
}
```

How to do that ?

Comment: It depends on your test setup. You can just override view method after creating it. Like `this.someView.attachSelect = function (){};`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The simplest way to mock a function is to replace the property at runtime.

You can provide your own monitoring function (commonly called a spy), although this is not the most elegant. That would look like:

```
var called = false;
var testee = new ViewUnderTest();
var originalAttach = testee.attachSelect; // cache a reference to the original
testee.attachSelect = function () {
  called = true;
  var args = [].concat(arguments); // get an array of arguments
  return originalAttach.apply(testee, args);
};

// Perform your test

expect(called).to.be.true;
```

If you have a test assertion library like [chai](http://chaijs.com/), you can use the [spies plugin](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-spies) and reduce that to:

```
var testee = new ViewUnderTest();
var spy = chai.spy(testee.attachSelect);
testee.attachSelect = spy;

// Perform your test

expect(spy).to.have.been.called();
```

Using a spy library will provide some useful features, such as monitoring the number of calls and their arguments to verify low-level behavior. If you're using Chai or Jasmine, I would highly suggest taking advantage of the corresponding support for spies.